# PHP script to download file in mobile Browser (Android)

Tags: php, android, mobile, download, mobile-browser

I want my mobile webapp be able to download files. My Android device unfortunately tells me it does not support file download via jquery plugin jquery.fileDownload.js...
So I just send a jsonP (cross domain, because my app runs on another server) request.

My php script looks

```
    ob_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.JPG"');
    readfile('/var/.../file.JPG');
    die();
```

In my android chrome browser nothing happens after I send the jsonp request.
What I am doing wrong? Isnt it possible to download files via jsonp? Same code tested
on my desktop browser works perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP requires you to send back actual executable javascript code. You're just dumping out some essentially random bytes, which your browser will try to execute, and fail miserably.

You need to do some reading first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

You'd need to respond with a proper JSONP callback, and include your file data as a parameter, e.g.

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo "jsonCallback(", json_encode(file_get_contents('your file here')); , ");"
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. But how can I tell the browser in jsonCallback method that it should start to download the json_encoded data?

Comment: THe parameter i get are just the file contents... As far as I know you cant start with javascript a download...

Comment: Read the wikipedia link. It explains the entire process.